# Kafka Spout not consuming message from some partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am new to Storm , 
These are my Storm Configuration

```
val builder = new TopologyBuilder()
  builder.setSpout("kafka-spout", new AlgoKafkaSpout().buildKafkaSpout(), 4)
  builder.setBolt("wlref-bolt", new WlrefBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping("kafka-spout")
  builder.setBolt("params-bolt", new ParamsBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping("wlref-bolt")
  builder.setBolt("gender-bolt", new GenderBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping("params-bolt")
  builder.setBolt("age-bolt", new AgeBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping("gender-bolt")
  builder.setBolt("preference-bolt", new PreferenceBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping("age-bolt")
  builder.setBolt("geo-bolt", new GeoBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping("preference-bolt")
  builder.setBolt("device-bolt", new DeviceBolt, 4).shuffleGrouping("geo-bolt")
  builder.setBolt("druid-bolt", new AlgoBeamBolt[java.util.Map[String, AnyRef]](new MyBeamFactory), 4)
   .shuffleGrouping("device-bolt")
  builder.setBolt("redis-bolt",new RedisBolt,4).shuffleGrouping("druid-bolt")

  val conf = new Config()
  conf.setDebug(false)
  conf.setMessageTimeoutSecs(120)
  conf.setNumWorkers(1)
  StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args(0), conf, builder.createTopology)
```

And this my KafkaSpout

```
val hosts = new ZkHosts(s"${Config.zkHost}:${Config.zkPort}") 
    val topic = Config.kafkaTopic 
    val zkRoot = s"/$topic"+"7" 
    val groupId = Config.kafkaGroup
    val kafkaConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topic, zkRoot, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    kafkaConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme())
    kafkaConfig.startOffsetTime = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime
    new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig)
```

We are producing approx 400 to 1000 messages per second. We make 4 partitions in Kafka Topic.
For few hours we consume message properly but after sometime kafkaSpout did not consume message from some partitions

This is message consuming report

[image]

Please let us know if any other information required.

**EDIT**

Kafka Version: kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1

Storm Version: apache-storm-0.10.2

Sbt Dependencies

```
"org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % "0.10.2" % "provided",
"org.apache.storm" % "storm-kafka" % "0.10.2" /*% "provided"*/,
"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.0.1"
```

Comment: You should share which exact version of 1. Storm (server version + the version you are compiling your topology against) and 2. Kafka your are using.

Comment: Hi @miguno I update my question please let me know if any other information you wants

Comment: Have you tried to use a newer version of Storm? The Kafka spout in Storm unfortunately doesn't have the best track record, so preferably you always want to use the latest version to get all the bug fixes.